Ways to access "Add to Custom Colors" or other extensions in <input type="color">
Is there currently any way to access "Add to Custom Colors" or other (local, browser or OS specific) extensions in the <input type="color"> Element?

(Old Aero theme example, aseen in Firefox.) This is probably a Windows-specific... quirk? vestige, even? -- but, it's interesting to me that the "Custom colors:" list can be populated from a datalist Element (via the list attribute), and also from within the dialog; but this state is lost when the dialog is closed, and it is re-initialized from the attached list with no state ever passed back to the document.
The MDN documentation for instance, doesn't mention anything specific, but I take that to mean there isn't anything currently developed for Firefox, nor stipulated in the underlying standard; but that doesn't mean no browsers support such means.
To be clear, I would expect -- if such a feature exists on any platform -- it might present as an array of color strings in the corresponding input event, or perhaps even the underling datalist is mutated to match (when so enabled by the document). But there are lots of ways this could be handled; my question is, was this ever done?
I'm also guessing, if such a feature exists anywhere at all, it's far from portable, so, I don't intend on using this for any actual content, just curious if this has been toyed with before.  And I expect there are more featureful libraries that provide such functionality natively [in JS and etc.], but this is also not my concern here.
Addendum: example of pre-filled entries:


The "custom colours" are an OS thing. Can't see you could populate them from any browser

I'm not sure that users are aware of defining custom favorite colors in their OS or use it at all. The Can I Use - Color input page links to the specification: specs: input color type. This links to the show the picker specs, which is a general-purpose definition for color, file, etc. picker workflow. I don't see anything user palette related there.

@PeterPointer Yes that's what I said, it would be nonstandard, a special feature.

@Bravo It works here, the filling part anyway. See edit. I was curious about extracting these data back to the document. Perhaps it has simply never been done, but I haven't used every browser on every platform, and that would be a foregone conclusion. A simple answer would affirm with an example; contradiction is not so easy unfortunately, but I wouldn't be shocked to see people who have used dozens of browsers in a development capacity and therefore have at least moderately authoritative knowledge on the subject.

I stand corrected

That was good idea so I made one for <input type="color"> unfortunately there's no way to control or measure the color picker. It also saves the custom colors in localStorage, but this version cannot save data since SO prohibits localStorage. Go to this Plunkerr to review a fully functional example. Both versions can manipulate the .value of input#color but it's position is static. The next update after position would be converting it into a component. Details are commented in the example.
The version saves data is here: Plunkerr


// * localStorage is prohibited on SO
// Reference <dialog>
const dialog = document.querySelector("dialog");
// Reference <form>
const palette = document.forms.palette;
// Reference all form controls in <form>
const io = palette.elements;
// Reference to <fieldset> with 48 basic color <button>s
const bSet = io.bSet;
// Reference to <fieldset> with 16 custom color <buttons>s
const cSet = io.cSet;
// Reference the <input type="color">
const color = io.color;

/**
 * Makes 48 basic color buttons and 16 custom color buttons
 */
const make = () => {
  const basicColors = ["#800000", "#990000", "#ff0000", "#800080", "#ff00ff", "#008000", "#00ff00", "#808000", "#ffff00", "#006666", "#0000ff", "#008080", "#00ffff", "#ff6300", "#3c6d00", "#90902b", "#a31d8b", "#b5d837", "#e59273", "#eb98ed", "#ac5450", "#174234", "#0ca1b7", "#fa71c8", "#babe22", "#724dcc", "#eba645", "#fc213b", "#ec6d8c", "#67eae1", "#585191", "#fa7653", "#279567", "#8b6eac", "#2ec679", "#4ba01b", "#942b8f", "#d5f375", "#a27a12", "#743cbd", "#2a7456", "#f0d14a", "#2b0bda", "#8de20a", "#4da5be", "#2731aa", "#69fc4c", "#cd42dd"];
  // Retrieve saved custom colors OR an array of 16 whites
  const customColors = /* JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("custom")) || */ Array(16).fill("#ffffff"); //⃰
  // Clear both <fieldset>s
  bSet.replaceChildren();
  cSet.replaceChildren();
  // Create and insert <legend> for basic colors
  const bTitle = `
        <legend>Basic Colors</legend>`;
  bSet.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", bTitle);
  // Create and insert 48 basic color <input type="button">s
  basicColors.forEach(b => {
    const square = `
      <input name="bColor" class="square" type="button" title="${b}" style="background-color: ${b}"  value="${b}">`;
    bSet.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", square);
  });
  // Create and insert <legend> for custom colors
  const cTitle = `
        <legend>Custom Colors</legend>`;
  cSet.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", cTitle);
  // Create and insert 16 custom color <input type="button">s
  customColors.forEach(c => {
    const square = `
      <input name="cColor" class="square" type="button" title="${c}" style="background-color: ${c}" value="${c}">`;
    cSet.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", square);
  });
  // Set the first custom color as .active
  io.cColor[0].classList.add("active");
};
/**
 * Delegates the "click" event for #add, [name="bColor"], and [name="cColor"]
 * buttons
 * @param {object} e - Event object
 */
const pick = e => {
  // e.target is the element that the user interacted with (eg. "clicked")
  const clk = e.target;
  // If the user clicked any [name="bColor"]...
  if (clk.name === "bColor") {
    // assign its .value to #color... 
    color.value = clk.value;
  }
  // if the user clicked any [name="cColor"]...
  if (clk.name === "cColor") {
    // assign its .value to #color...
    color.value = clk.value;
    // then gather them into an array and remove .active...
    Array.from(io.cColor).forEach(c => c.classList.remove("active"));
    // and add .active to the one that the user clicked.
    clk.classList.add("active");
  }
  // if the user clicked #add button...
  if (clk.id === "add") {
    // find the .active button...
    const act = document.querySelector(".active");
    // assign #color .value to .active's .title, background, and .value
    act.title = color.value;
    act.style.backgroundColor = color.value;
    act.value = color.value;
  }
};
/**
 * Opens the <dialog> when #color is clicked
 * @param {object} e - Event object
 */
const open = e => {
  // If the user clicked #color...
  if (e.target.id === "color") {
    // open <dialog>...
    dialog.show();
    // make the color buttons...
    make();
    // then remove the eventListener
    color.removeEventListener("click", open);
  }
};
/**
 * Runs when <dialog> closes or cancelled
 * @param {object} e - Event object
 */
const exit = e => {
  // Determine which event was fired
  const evt = e.type;
  /*
   If user cancelled by pressing the [esc] key OR the Cancel button was
   clicked, end function.
  */
  if (evt === "cancel" || e.target.returnValue === "Cancel") {
    return;
  }
  // Create an array of .values from all [name="cColor"]
  const custom = Array.from(io.cColor).map(c => c.value);
  // Save the array to localStorage⃰ 
  // localStorage.setItem("custom", JSON.stringify(custom));
  // Add the eventListener back
  color.addEventListener("click", open);
};

/**
 * EventListeners for "click", "cancel", and "close" events
 */
color.addEventListener("click", open);
palette.addEventListener("click", pick);
dialog.addEventListener("close", exit);
dialog.addEventListener("cancel", exit);
:root {
  font: 2ch/1.2 "Segoe UI"
}

.area {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
}

#color {
  position: absolute;
}

dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 2px;
  border: 1.51515px outset rgb(240, 240, 240);
  border-top-color: rgb(200 200 200);
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: rgb(38, 57, 77) 0px 20px 30px -10px;
}

fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 3px;
  max-width: 220px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 2px 5px -1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 3px -1px;
}

button,
#color {
  display: block;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 2px 4px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 7px 13px -3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px -3px 0px inset;
}

.square {
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 1px inset rgb(128 128 128);
  font-size: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btns {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  min-width: 245px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: transparent 0 0 0;
}

#add {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.active {
  outline: 2px solid rgb(140 0 0);
  outline-offset: 1px;
}
<section class="area">
  <input id="color" type="color" form="palette">

  <dialog>
    <form id="palette" method="dialog">
      <label for="color">
        <fieldset id="bSet" name="frame"></fieldset>
        <fieldset id="cSet" name="frame"></fieldset>
      </label>
      <fieldset class="btns">
        <button id="add" type="button">Add Color</button>
        <button value="OK">OK</button>
        <button value="Cancel">Cancel</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </dialog>
</section>




This isn't the answer I'm looking for, but it may be useful to others looking for an actually portable solution.

The basic color section is prefiled (like Win8) and the custom colors can be saved (not sure if that was a thing). Are you looking for <select> or <datalist> that's way easier than this interface.

Wait, which browser, version and OS are you using? Do you mean 1. you get a Windows color dialog and 2. the document receives the "add custom colors" done within said dialog (not just entries preloaded into it)? You'll probably need to post a short gif or clip or something to demo that...

@TimWilliams Actually you just click  the "Run Code Snippet" button, or click the "Plunker" button if you want to see it save custom colors indefinitely using localStorage. That's the only thing this Snippet can't do because SO blocks localStorage. The positioning isn't perfect because <input type=-"color"> color picker can't be controlled or measured. I probably have to make the other panel using <canvas>.

Perhaps there is a miscommunication here. I think I've been very precise in what I've described but perhaps not. I'm not concerned about persistent storage, I'm concerned about 1. populating the "Custom colors:" list (this occurs, for at least one combination of browser and OS), and 2. returning such a list (that can be modified by the user while the dialog is open) to the document where it can be subsequently stored (persistently or otherwise). Your example does not do this universally at least; see: https://i.sstatic.net/oJWdnLxA.png

What OS and browser are you using and what environment (eg. online editor, locally, etc..). Here's Win Chrome locally. I would've recorded on Plunker as well but it's too slow for some reason. "...this occurs, for at least one combination of browser and OS" Ok, which combo?

Which version did you copy? Also if it failed to save to localStorage there should be an error logged, the way I code if something fails it usually does'nt fail silently.

In Firefox 115 / Win7 (I have an old machine I keep for occasional dev work), clicking the original square, or otherwise-inactive regions of the dialog element, still brings up the OS picker widget (seems the click event isn't properly disposed of...or perhaps can't be). And to further clarify: I'm not talking about making a new dialog to replicate this function ("And I expect there are more featureful libraries that provide such functionality natively [in JS and etc.], but this is also not my concern here"), my curiosity is strictly about interactions with the OS dialog.

Your tags are [JavaScript] and [html] and while they are affected by OS (many things are), browsers are the dominant factor as to what features are available. This topic isn't really a question of OS as it is more to do with browsers. Firefox is a perfect example when it comes to the color picker. Moreover I wrapped a <label> associated to #color around the two <fieldset> in order to keep the picker focused, but it'll never happen. Just remove <label for="color">.

Oh yeah the <label> would do it

Win7 can still handle Chrome 109, Firefox 115, and Edge 109 which were all released in 2023. Here's a quote from your post, "Is there currently any way to access "Add to Custom Colors" or other (local, browser or OS specific) extensions in the  Element?". My functions do the same thing it's just clunky.

Access, in the sense of, from document level, hence the JS tag. There are data in these cells, but can it be accessed from the document?

Everything my functions do is basically DOM (Document Object Model).

BTW you should copy the code in the Plunker it saves custom colors to localStorage if you click the OK 

Yes, but your functions are entirely within DOM, or only receive a color from the HTML picker interface. I'm curious about receiving data other than the color value promulgated in the web standard. The "Custom colors:" entries are not returned to the document, nor does the "Add to Custom Colors" button produce an event.
